# MVC4 application on handling list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is my model class with two classes Employee and Employee list

```
 namespace EditMultiplerecords.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Employeelist : IEnumerable<Employee>
    {
        public List<Employee> employee { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<Employee> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return employee.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return employee.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my View  where i am writing code for editing using javascript

```
    @model EditMultiplerecords.Models.Employeelist
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Homepage";
}
<link href="../../Content/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $('.editor input').blur(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).closest('p').find('label').html($(this).val()).show();

        });

        $('.editor label').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).closest('p').find('input').show();

        });
    });
</script>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    using (Html.BeginForm())
    { 
    <div class="editor">
        <p>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Id)
            @Html.LabelFor(x => item.Name, item.Name)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => item.Name)
            <input type="submit" value="OK" />
        </p>
    </div> 

    }
@*        @Html.Partial("Details", item);*@
}
```

And this controller class

```
  public ActionResult Homepage()
    {
        Employeelist el = new Employeelist();
        el.employee = new List<Employee>();
        el.employee.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Rahul" });
        el.employee.Add(new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "America" });
        el.employee.Add(new Employee { Id = 3, Name = "NewJersey" });
        return View(el);

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Homepage(Employeelist el)
    {
        return View(el);
    }
```

My problem is when i edit Rahul or America or NewJersey, on Post Action iam getting an empty list with null values rather an updated list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `@foreach (var item in Model)` loop inside `using (Html.BeginForm())` to accept modified List

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    { 
    <div class="editor">
        <p>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Id)
            @Html.LabelFor(x => item.Name, item.Name)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => item.Name)
        </p>
    </div> 

    }
}
       <input type="submit" value="OK" />

@*        @Html.Partial("Details", item);*@
```

> -- Edit Accept formCollection

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Homepage(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var itemid = formCollection.GetValue("item.id");
    var itemname= formCollection.GetValue("item.name");
---//use values to send it back to view----
    return View();
}
```

Comment: see updated code. i close form at wrong place. Submit button need to be outside of Form

Comment: for the first time i am able to display data but on Post i am unable to store updated list it is becoming null and for each and every item i want a button so i kept it inside

Comment: Ohh. we Passing List to Model and accepting back a single item from View to controllor to support muiltiple Submit buttons on View. See My Edit

Comment: i also want the remaining items on Post back ,i am getting single item

Comment: So to summarise you will have  sepreate form and submit buttons for each record. On each submit you want all 3 records in differnt form sent across to Controllor Action. I think you need to revist your requirement from users prespective.

Comment: I am able to get all values but how to convert form collection to a list